# Problems trying to read dbf file in C#

Tags: c#, dbf

I am trying to read a dbf file in C#, but first I had the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The provider' Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 'is not registered on the local machine.'

Then I installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable and now I have the error

> The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file 'C:\Users\Emmanuel\Desktop\Proyectos\program'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.'

This is the code I'm using:

```cs
var constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
var sql = "select * from " + file;
var ds = new DataTable();

using (var con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
{
    con.Open();

    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con))
    {
        using (var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
}
```

Also I've tried this but I have this error

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft] [ODBC dBase Driver] The external table is not in the expected format.'

```cs
string fullPath = path + file;
string sConn = "Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=" + path + ";Exclusive=No; NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;";

using (OdbcConnection dbConn = new OdbcConnection(sConn))
{
    dbConn.Open();
    OdbcCommand oCmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
    oCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + fullPath;

    /* Load data to table */

    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1.Load(oCmd.ExecuteReader());
    dbConn.Close();
}
```

Comment: try to put the database file in `C drive` or `D drive` instead user folder such as Desktop

Comment: Still the same errors

Comment: The "file '..\program'" sounds like your path is to the *folder* where that dbf file is, instead of to the file itself

Comment: What do you know about that "dbf" file? What application created it? (an Access driver may not be the correct one, but dBase sounds correct based on the dbf tag description)